# SSL implementation in Spring Security Form Login Tomcat

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-security, https, tomcat7

I'm trying to migrate an Web App made with Spring Security over https.
I followed ALL the guides and documentations found over the web, but it didn't work nothing. Could you help me to solve the problem or to identify the problems?

Don't work because when I go to https://mywebapps I get a page not found. While http work.

I followed this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https for the keystore and connector configuration.

I run webapp over AWS EC2.

mywebapp/web-application-context.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/Unsecure/NoPermission" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/Unsecure/Login" 
            login-processing-url="/Unsecure/Login.do" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" always-use-default-target="true"
            default-target-url="/Secure/Home/Dashboard" authentication-failure-url="/Unsecure/Login?err=1" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/Unsecure/Login"
            logout-url="/Secure/Logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <security:csrf />
        <security:http-basic/>
    </security:http>
```

tomcat7/server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
            sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"/>
```

mywebapp/web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Best reguards,
Carmine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you modified the security group for the EC2 instance to allow incoming connections to TCP port 8443.

You can also use wget from the instance shell itself to determine if its serving pages via HTTPS as such:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

Hmm, rereading your configuration, do you have a reverse proxy in front of your Tomcat that is going to route requests at port 443 to your Tomcat listening on port 8443?  If not, you should be accessing your Tomcat with https://mywebapp:8443 for HTTPS not https://mywebapp.

Comment: Hi, I run the above command and I get:
--2019-10-08 12:47:21--  https://mywebapps:8443/
Resolving mywebapps (mywebapps)... xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to mywebapps (mywebapps)|xx.xx.xxx.xxx|:8443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: Also did you confirm it is not a security group issue?

Comment: Also what version of wget are you using (wget --version)?

Comment: Run the wget with the -v and --debug options so we can get more details on why its failing: wget -v --debug --no-check-certificate '127.0.0.1:8443'

Comment: Yes I confirm that. The security group is setting correct.
Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.18 on linux-gnu.
Reading HSTS entries from /home/user/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2019-10-08 13:14:41--  https://mywebapps:8443/
Resolving mywebapps (mywebapps)... xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Caching mywebapps => xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to mywebapps (mywebapps)|xx.xx.xxx.xxx|:8443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000002491f30 (new refcount 1).

Comment: Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Closed fd 3
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: By the way when I had used the RapidSSL cert bought online I had got a ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.

Comment: Can you try adding this to your HTTPS connector in your server.xml:
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"

Comment: I did it but nothing. I get the same error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.
I have got these files: csr_for_certificate.key;intermeiate_cert.crt;certificate.crt;domainname.p7s;rsa_for_certificate.key; keystore.kdb; I create only the last one file, and add in it the cert files. Maybe I did somthing wrong

Comment: Sorry, I assume you restarted the Tomcat server afterwards?  This is a strange one!

Comment: This is a stretch, but can you make your EC2 instance temporarily publicly accessible on that port so I can try to connect from here?

Comment: Try using openssl to get more debug information:
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -debug -tls1 -msg

Comment: solved I recreate the keystore starting from privatekey and certificate. Sorry. How can avoid to write port number?

Comment: Based on the above configuration, Can I implement both BAuth and Form login? I tried to add security:http-basc but not work.

Comment: Glad you resolved it!  It is not recommended to address multiple questions within one question.  If this is a separate issue, please start a new question.  Also please consider adding how you resolved it as a separate answer and mark it as accepted for posterity.